# Kibana - can I replace "no results found" with custom message

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I have discovered Kibana last week and I am wondering if it is possible to replace that "No results found" communicate with custom message?

I am preparing very huge dashboard and it will almost always contain some visuals that in perfect life should not display any results (because they are for errors).

I am not pleased with my current results because while there are no errors it looks like I just don't posses any knowledge of them.

Comment: I don't think you can do that currently. Same issue has been raised at https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/7530. You should follow it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can change the message. And I tried this with kibana-4.X. There is a file called `visualize.html` in `kibana-4.X\src\ui\public\visualize` directory. The file consist of the following source.

```
<div ng-if="showNoResultsMessage()"
  class="text-center visualize-error visualize-chart">
  <div class="item top"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2 aria-hidden="true"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-meh-o"></i></h2>
    <h4>No results found</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item bottom"></div>
</div>
<div ng-hide="showNoResultsMessage()" class="vis-container">
  <div ng-style="loadingStyle"
    ng-class="{ loading: vis.type.requiresSearch && searchSource.activeFetchCount > 0 }"
    class="visualize-chart">
  </div>
  <visualize-legend></visualize-legend>
</div>
<!-- <pre>{{chartData | json}}</pre> -->
<visualize-spy ng-if="vis.type.requiresSearch && showSpyPanel"></visualize-spy>
```

In h4 tag you can provide your custom message whatever you wanted to show. After changing the message you have to empty the `kibana-4.X\optimize` directory in order to get the changes effect in your kibana.

Comment: Sorry, but that's editing core files, which is not proper way of changing functionalities.

Maybe you have some method of extending that functionality in some plugin? I need something similar (additional attribute in visualize-legend.html. I want to extend that functionality/ replace html variable in m,y Kibana plugin)